# How to program a set operation expression as an argument of a function?

Tags: r, function, set, metaprogramming, lazy-evaluation

If I have function `f`:

```r
f <- function(a = character(0),
              b = character(0),
              c = character(0),
              condition = "a + b + c") {

  if(condition == "a + b + c")
    return(union(union(a, b), c))

  if(condition == "(a * b) + c")
    return(union(intersect(a, b), c))

  if(condition == "(a - b) + c")
    return(union(setdiff(a, b), c))

  if(condition == "(a - b) - c")
    return(setdiff(setdiff(a, b), c))

  # etc...

}


f(a = c('1', '2', '3'),
  b = c('2', '3', '4'),
  c = c('3', '4'),
  condition = "a + b + c")
#> [1] "1" "2" "3" "4"

f(a = c('1', '2'),
  b = c('2', '3'),
  c = c('2', '3', '4'),
  condition = "(a * b) + c")
#> [1] "2" "3" "4"

f(a = c('1', '2'),
  b = c('2', '3'),
  c = c('2', '3', '4'),
  condition = "(a - b) - c")
#> [1] "1"
```

How to approach the problem of coding that argument `condition` which ought to define a set operation expression on the input vectors?

In my example I've used simple strings just to exemplify the intended behaviour, however this solution does not scale well. Do I need to use a language object(?!)...

I need a simple way of:

1. specifying this expression (a string might be a good object?);
2. parse it somehow and make sure it translates to a valid set operation expression;
3. Compute the result by applying the aforementioned set operation expression.

Comment: @RichScriven: Sorry I picked those examples too quickly from the top of my head... but actually the type of the vector is not that relevant as long as it is assumed to be the same for all input vectors.

Comment: You're essentially nesting two operations. Could it be better to have one function that operates on a * b. where * can be any operation you define (setdiff, union, interesect etc) then you can have an outer function that can run function 1 on a\*b = y then function 1 again on y\*c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One thing you could do would be just to parse the expression, then replace `+`, `-` and `*` with the appropriate functions. Then you can just evaulate that expression. For example

```
f <- function(a = character(0),
              b = character(0),
              c = character(0),
              condition = "a + b + c") {

  parsed_cond <- parse(text=condition)[[1]]
  translated_expr <- do.call("substitute", list(
      parsed_cond,
      list(`+`=quote(union),
           `-`=quote(setdiff),
           `*`=quote(intersect))
   ))
   eval(translated_expr)
}
```

This returns the values you give in your example

Comment: That's really neat! I am just wondering how to do checking on the `condition` argument, i.e., validate it as a bona fide expression... I don't want to expose nasty errors from that substitute call to the user.. Do you have a suggestion on how to make sure `condition` is actually made of the previous arguments and of `+`, `-`, `*`, and eventually `(` and `)`?

Comment: It depends on what exactly you want to be tolerant of and exactly what you want error messages to say. You could tryCatch the parse() to check for valid expressions. Or you could define a regular expression perhaps to validate input.

Comment: ok! Do you mind decomposing a bit that command in small steps so that it is more edible (I am still struggling with lazy evaluation).

Comment: As far as I know that parse call returns an expression object, you extract the first element (a language object I think), then you wrap it in a list, and concatenate with whatnot... :)

Comment: I added in a few temp variables so you can debug the function and see what it's doing at each step.